# Can't SSH into Rasberry Pi from Computer connected to Bridge on the Pi

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, bridge

**Background:**

I have a Windows PC, which was previously connected with ethernet straight to my router, which gave it internet access.

I also have a Raspberry Pi with 2 physical ethernet interfaces,  which is connected via one of the said ethernet interfaces into my router,(`eth0` & `eth1`) which gives the Pi internet access ( have tried using both interfaces for this successfully, so I know they both work)

For a project I'm doing, I have created a bridge, which contains the interfaces `eth0` & `eth1` , and I have one interface connected to the router and one connected to the Windows PC.

With this configuration I have internet access on my Windows PC, meaning the bridge works. But the Pi itself does not have internet access (Tested trying `ping 8.8.8.8` and `wget 8.8.8.8`, which worked without the bridge.)

I also cannot SSH into the Pi from my Windows PC, and receive a "connection has timed out" error when trying to do so ( Has worked numerous times, I frequently use Putty or MobaXTerm to access the Pi)

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to be able to have internet access for my windows PC (or anything on the other side of the bridge), still have internet access on the Raspberry Pi, and be able to SSH into the Pi from the "non-router" side of the network?

(It is more important for me to be able to SSH into the Pi, having internet access would just be a bonus!)

Any and all help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The solution might be to create a tap interface on the Pi, and add that interface to the bridge. The tap-interface should get an IP address that is correct for your local LAN. Your eth0/eth1 probably don't need an IP address anymore then.

```
ip tuntap add name tap0 mode tap
brctl addbr mybridge
brctl addif mybridge eth0
brctl addif mybridge eth1
brctl addif mybridge tap0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
ifconfig mybridge up
ifconfig tap0 192.168.100.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

An alternative would be to give the bridge on the pi an IP address.

```
brctl addbr mybridge
brctl addif mybridge eth0
brctl addif mybridge eth1
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
ifconfig eth1 0.0.0.0
ifconfig mybridge up
ifconfig mybridge 192.168.100.5 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to assign an IP to the bridge interface (and not eth0 or eth1) and get an IP and the needed routes.

Depending on the two network segments running `dhclient br0` (assuming the bridge has the device `br0`) may work, otherwise a static IP may be better especially when both network segments have a DHCP server running.